# SQl query group by year different columns where condition apply

Tags: sql

I am not coming right with this.

I have this table "bids" in SQL 2012:

> | custDecDate | forBid | valueXX | valueYY |

I would like to sum the values relevant "valueXX" and "ValueYY" separately and grouped per year "custDecDate" where the value of column  "forBid" = For Contract

"custDecDate" is a datetime and contains date dd/MM/yyyy, valueXX and valueYY are int and "forBid" is a nvarchar.

I am very lost. Any help is welcomed, I need a starting point to learn this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(custDecDate), SUM(valueXX), SUM(valueYY)
FROM bids
WHERE forBid = "For Contract"
GROUP BY YEAR(custDecDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

the query should be really simple....

Oracle:

```
Select trunc(custDecDate,'YYYY'), sum(valueXX), sum(valueYY)
from bids
where forBid = '...'
group by trunc(custDecDate,'YYYY')
```

MSSQL:

```
Select year(custDecDate), sum(valueXX), sum(valueYY)
from bids
where forBid = '...'
group by year(custDecDate)
```

Did I answer what you meant?

Comment: It is working too. But arrived a picosecond later. +

Comment: I'm an Oracle guy, took me a minute to find the MSSQL syntax.. LOL